# Help with Sharepoint List Columns - make cell GREEN if value = "Complete"

Tags: sharepoint-online

Need help with Sharepoint - I have created a list, and my boss wants a cell on a specific column to turn green if the value = "Complete".  Is this possible?  The particular column name is "MCH" in case that helps with the this.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modern SharePoint list and the status column is a choice, you can simply do the following:

- Go the the "Column settings" > "Format this column":

[image]

- Click "Choice pills" > "Advanced Mode":

[image]

Inser the following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField == 'Complete', '#BAD80B','')"
  }
}
```

**You'll get this result**

[image]

If you want a more fancy format, you can use the following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Status]",
                "Complete"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-greenLight",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Status]",
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                "",
                "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "style": {
            "line-height": "16px",
            "height": "14px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Status]",
                    "Complete"
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Status]",
                        ""
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "style": {
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
            "padding": "0 3px"
          },
          "txtContent": "[$Status]",
          "attributes": {
            "class": {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Status]",
                    "Complete"
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Status]",
                        ""
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- Replace `$Status` with the name of your column. For example, ff it's called "Outcome", then `$Status` should be replaced with `$Outcome`

**Result**

[image]